# Htlatex and beamer, strange output with \emph

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I'm seeing some strange output for `\emph` text using `htlatex` with the `beamer` class.  Using the following source:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \emph{bold text}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \emph{bold text}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and compiling with

```
pdflatex test.tex
mk4ht htlatex test.tex 'xhtml,html5,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

I see the following HTML output (reformatted for readability, but otherwise unmodified):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
    <head>
        <title></title> 
        <meta  charset="utf-8" /> 
        <meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" /> 
        <meta name="src" content="test.tex" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="cmss-12x-x-120">Test</span>                                                               
        <!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >
            <span class="cmssi-10x-x-109">bold text </span>
        </p>
        <ul class="itemize1">
            <li class="itemize">
                <span class="cmssi-10x-x-109">bold</span>
                <span class="cmssi-10x-x-109">text</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body> 
</html>
```

As you can see, all `\emph` text is enclosed in `<span>` tags, and additionally `\emph` text within the `itemize` environment is separated into individual words, each in its own span.

No amount of `\Configure{emph}` in a config file affects this behaviour.

Clearly the output could be made to look right despite this weirdness.  However my use case is generating accessible versions of content from presentation slides, so it's important to me to have semantically appropriate tags (e.g. `<em>`) and contiguous spans.

Is there a simple way to override this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer patches common font commands in order to support overlays. For most of them, it uses the original command definition, so `tex4ht` configurations still work. But it redefines `\emph` completely, so the configuration doesn't have any effect. It needs to be inserted again in `beamer.4ht`:

```
\let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
\def\pgf@trimright@final{0pt}
\def\pgf@trimleft@final{0pt}
\let\origEndP\EndP
\AtBeginDocument{\def\EndP{\let\EndP\origEndP}\SaveEndP}

% Beamer redefines \emph, it is necessary to insert hooks again

\pend:defI\emph{\a:emph}%
\append:defI\emph{\b:emph}%

\endinput
```

The configuration may look like this (this contains also configuration for slide insertion):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{emph}{\HCode{<em>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</em>}}

\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{beamer@frameslide}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP
    \HCode{<section class="slide">}\RecallEndP\par\ShowPar
   }
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP \HCode{</section>}}
   {} {}
\makeatother
\Css{section.slide {border:solid black 0.4pt;margin-bottom:1em;}}


\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

And this is the result:

```xml
<section class="slide">


<span 
class="cmss-12x-x-120">Test</span>                                                               
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" ><em>bold text</em> </p>
    <ul class="itemize1">
    <li class="itemize">
    <em>italic
    text</em></li></ul>


</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this once my toddler is asleep. Is beamer.4ht picked up automatically or do I have to add it to the htlatex arguments somewhere like I would with the config?

Comment: It is picked automatically if it is placed in the same directory as the Tex file