# tex4ht and beamer, re-patching \section

Tags: beamer, tex4ht, htlatex

I'm using tex4ht to generate accessible versions of presentations created using the beamer package.  Beamer redefines `\section` and friends, and so the tex4ht configuration hooks are lost.  I know how to restore them for a simple command thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501602/51351) to a previous question, but the `\section` commands are significantly more complex, not least because tex4ht somehow provides an 'end of section' hook which is not trivial.

How can I restore the hooks for `\section` and friends, to take advantage of `\Configure{section}` etc. in tex4ht?